# Error 404 on my github page with Create-react-app. it is a simple app with no routing

Tags: reactjs

404
There isn't a GitHub Pages site here.

I have readme.md file.
Have uploaded project on master branch.

when I run $npm run deploy command. It says published. But couldnt find my github pages link on my repository.

Comment: You didn't ask any question. What is your question?

Comment: How to resolve it?? 404 There isn't a GitHub Pages site here. I get this error.

Answer (score 0):

I changed my repository from Private to public it worked.